# php host status from php mysql database

Tags: ping

Help me!!
Seem when i run the scripts, the output seems wrong :(

This is the output...

[Here My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGTpb.png)

The 1st and 3rd entry is true, online

But the rest should be **OFFLINE** but the output shows **all ONLINE**

I think the problem is from **foreach loop** but I cannot figure out how to solve the problem

Please help me... :(

```
<table border="1">
<thead>

    <tr>
        <th>Entry</th>
        <th>Host</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Availability</th>
    </tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM host_entry";
$no  = 1;

//foreach($dbh->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)

$dbhi = $dbh->query($sql);

foreach ($dbhi->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH) as $data) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data['host_server']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data['host_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data['host_location']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data['host_desc']; ?></td>
        <td>
        <?php  
        $ip = $data["host_server"];
                    // Run the ping to the IP
                    exec ("ping -n 1 -w 1 $ip", $ping_output);

                    if(preg_match("/Reply/i", $ping_output[2])!==0) {
                        echo "<font color='green'><strong>Online!</strong></font>";
                    }
                    else if(preg_match("/Reply/i", $ping_output[2])===0){
                        echo "<font color='red'><strong>Offline!</strong></font>";
                    }
        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>

</tbody>
```